# R: flatten inner part of a list of lists while keeping its structure

Tags: r, list, vector, dplyr, data.table

I am running a simulation study where my results are stored in a nested list structure. The first level of the list represents the different hyperparameters generated by the model. The second level is the number of replications of the same model (changing the seed).

In the example below, I list the output of a model that is governed by two hyperparameters (hyperpar1 and hyperpar2) where both can take 2 different values, leading to 4 different combinations of the resulting model. Additionally, each of the 4 possible combinations was run twice (different seeds), leading to eight possible combinations (as can be seen below with `str(res, max = 2)`). Finally, two performance metrics were recovered from each possible iteration of the models (metric1 and metric2) and also the value of the two parameters of the model `beta = list(b1 = value, b2 = value)`.

My problem is related to the last part. I want to flatten the list `beta` and get each component inside of the list as a component of the upper list that contains it, but keeping the whole structure described in the beginning unchanged.

Below an example:

#### Sample of the data.

```
res <-list(
  list(list(modeltype = "tree", time_iter = structure(0.7099, class = "difftime", units = "secs"),seed = 1, nobs = 75, hyperpar1 = 0.5, hyperpar2 = 0.5, metric1 = 0.4847, metric2 = 0.2576, beta = list(b1 = 0.575, b2 =0.745)),     
       list(modeltype = "tree", time_iter = structure(0.058 , class = "difftime", units = "secs"),seed = 2, nobs = 75, hyperpar1 = 0.5, hyperpar2 = 0.5, metric1 = 0.4013, metric2 = 0.2569, beta = list(b1 = 0.535, b2 =0.775))), 
  list(list(modeltype = "tree", time_iter = structure(0.046 , class = "difftime", units = "secs"),seed = 1, nobs = 75, hyperpar1 = 0.8, hyperpar2 = 0.5, metric1 = 0.4755, metric2 = 0.2988, beta = list(b1 = 0.541, b2 =0.702) ), 
       list(modeltype = "tree", time_iter = structure(0.0474, class = "difftime", units = "secs"),seed = 2, nobs = 75, hyperpar1 = 0.8, hyperpar2 = 0.5, metric1 = 0.2413, metric2 = 0.2147, beta = list(b1 = 0.545, b2 =0.793) )), 
  list(list(modeltype = "tree", time_iter = structure(0.0502, class = "difftime", units = "secs"),seed = 1, nobs = 75, hyperpar1 = 0.5, hyperpar2 = 1  , metric1 = 0.7131, metric2 = 0.5024, beta = list(b1 = 0.500, b2 =0.722) ), 
       list(modeltype = "tree", time_iter = structure(2.9419, class = "difftime", units = "secs"),seed = 2, nobs = 75, hyperpar1 = 0.5, hyperpar2 = 1  , metric1 = 0.4254, metric2 = 0.2824, beta = list(b1 = 0.555, b2 =0.712) )), 
  list(list(modeltype = "tree", time_iter = structure(0.041 , class = "difftime", units = "secs"),seed = 1, nobs = 75, hyperpar1 = 0.8, hyperpar2 = 1  , metric1 = 0.6709, metric2 = 0.4092, beta = list(b1 = 0.578, b2 =0.701) ), 
       list(modeltype = "tree", time_iter = structure(0.0396, class = "difftime", units = "secs"),seed = 2, nobs = 75, hyperpar1 = 0.8, hyperpar2 = 1  , metric1 = 0.4585, metric2 = 0.4115, beta = list(b1 = 0.501, b2 =0.777) )))
```

#### Illustration of the obtained output.

```
str(res[[1]][[1]], max = 3)
# List of 9
# $ modeltype: chr "tree"
# $ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.7099
# ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
# $ seed     : num 1
# $ nobs     : num 75
# $ hyperpar1: num 0.5
# $ hyperpar2: num 0.5
# $ metric1  : num 0.485
# $ metric2  : num 0.258
# $ beta     :List of 2  #### <----- ( here is what I want to flatten/unlist ) 
# ..$ b1: num 0.575 
# ..$ b2: num 0.745
```

#### Desired output (betas flattened)

```
str(res[[1]][[1]], max = 3)
# List of 9
# $ modeltype: chr "tree"
# $ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.7099
# ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
# $ seed     : num 1
# $ nobs     : num 75
# $ hyperpar1: num 0.5
# $ hyperpar2: num 0.5
# $ metric1  : num 0.485
# $ metric2  : num 0.258
# $ b1: num 0.575 #### <----- ( here is new  because  ) 
# $ b2: num 0.745 #### <----- ( this part is flat now! )
```

PS: as a side note, the simulation takes a couple of days to complete, and not all the time the number of parameters is constant across the models; this is why I want to flatten the list `beta` no matter what it is inside of it. Packaged solutions are welcome (e,g,.`data.table` or `dplyr`). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for the real data, but it seems to produce the desire for the example data above.

`map_depth(res, 2, flatten)`

Here is the full output with `str`:

```r
library(purrr)

map_depth(res, 2, flatten) %>% str

#> List of 4
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: num 0.71
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 1
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.485
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.258
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.575
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.745
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: num 0.058
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 2
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.401
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.257
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.535
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.775
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: num 0.046
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 1
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.8
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.475
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.299
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.541
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.702
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: num 0.0474
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 2
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.8
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.241
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.215
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.545
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.793
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: num 0.0502
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 1
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 1
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.713
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.502
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.722
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: num 2.94
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 2
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 1
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.425
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.282
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.555
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.712
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: num 0.041
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 1
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.8
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 1
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.671
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.409
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.578
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.701
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: num 0.0396
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 2
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.8
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 1
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.459
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.411
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.501
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.777
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Update**

The problem of the approach above is that all other variables are converted to `numeric`, which is not desirable, since `time_iter` was originally a `difftime` object.

The approach below is more verbose, but doesn't convert other variables to `numeric`:

```r
res %>%
  map(
    ~ modify(.x, function(x) {
      x <- append(x, unlist(x$beta))
      x$beta <- NULL 
      x
      })
```

Below is the output of `str`:

```r
res %>%
  map(
    ~ modify(.x, function(x) {
      x <- append(x, unlist(x$beta))
      x$beta <- NULL 
      x
      })
  ) %>% str

#> List of 4
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.7099
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 1
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.485
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.258
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.575
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.745
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.058
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 2
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.401
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.257
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.535
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.775
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.046
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 1
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.8
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.475
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.299
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.541
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.702
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.0474
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 2
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.8
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.241
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.215
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.545
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.793
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.0502
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 1
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 1
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.713
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.502
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.722
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 2.9419
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 2
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 1
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.425
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.282
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.555
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.712
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.041
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 1
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.8
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 1
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.671
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.409
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.578
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.701
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
#>   .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.0396
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#>   .. ..$ seed     : num 2
#>   .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.8
#>   .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 1
#>   .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.459
#>   .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.411
#>   .. ..$ b1       : num 0.501
#>   .. ..$ b2       : num 0.777
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @TimTeaFan! I would like to ask if you know how to preserve the nature of the objects inside the list? For example, I would like to preserve the fact that `time_iter` is a `difftime` object. Your solution seems to force them to be numbers (meaning that I lose the units in which the time was measured). Thanks again!

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas I updated my answer! Its possible, but more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
res2 <- map_depth(res, 2, ~ list_flatten(., name_spec = "{inner}"))

str(res2)
List of 4
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 10
  .. ..$ modeltype: chr "tree"
  .. ..$ time_iter: 'difftime' num 0.7099
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
  .. ..$ seed     : num 1
  .. ..$ nobs     : num 75
  .. ..$ hyperpar1: num 0.5
  .. ..$ hyperpar2: num 0.5
  .. ..$ metric1  : num 0.485
  .. ..$ metric2  : num 0.258
  .. ..$ b1       : num 0.575
  .. ..$ b2       : num 0.745
```